# Unable to toggle div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm working on a project using jQuery and ASP.Net. What I'm trying to do is create a button that hide/show a div using jQuery. Here is the code that I have used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//FR" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <title> Gestion des projets et des demandes </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" >
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.minimize_button').click(function () {
                    $('#my_div_example').stop().toggle('slow');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <input type="submit" value="_" class="minimize_button"  />
            <div class="big_div_content" id="my_div_example"></div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems to not work, what did I do wrong?

Comment: it s just doesnt work , at first second the div seems to be hidden then it back visible again , i have tried the same code with an html file it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this working fiddle  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5eh8/)

You did event on click of submit ,so form is submitted , u can use div.Or use prevent submit on click of Submit button.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div class="minimize_button">clickme</div>
          <div class="big_div_content" id="my_div_example">
               This is toggling
           </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: lool that was easy , thank you so much ,  work perfectly as i wanted it to :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

what is XML doing there?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Second, you won't detect any change

```
 $('#my_div_example').stop().toggle('slow');
```

Because `div` has no content. It is invisible to you. So, the idea to you, would be to include some content to the div

```
<div class="big_div_content" id="my_div_example">
   Some text...
</div>
```

Comment: i just tried to make the example here as simple as i could , my real div has content in it

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
i forgot it because i copied content for my html file to my asp page